# installing mysql2 gem on redhat

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redhat, mysql2

Currently trying to install the mysql2 gem on redhat.  This is what I'm getting after running gem install

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.18 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config


checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

It looks like most people who get a similar error need to install mysql dev/lib packages.  The packages are already installed and up to date. The mkmf.log file looks like this:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward 
    -I/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I. -I/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 
    -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings 
    -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. 
    -L/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib -Wl,-R/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib -L/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib -lruby-static  -lpthread -lrt 
    -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"

In file included from /home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33,
    from conftest.c:1:
/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:107: error: size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_long' is negative
/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:111: error: size of array 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' is negative
In file included from /home/zdorman/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33,
    from conftest.c:1:
/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_int2num_inline':
/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1303: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1303: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_uint2num_inline':
/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1313: warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
In file included from /home/zdorman/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:35,
    from /home/zdorman/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1710,
    from /home/zdorman/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby.h:33,
    from conftest.c:1:
/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/st.h: At top level:
/home/zdev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/st.h:52: error: size of array 'st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t' is negative
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

The errors in the log file are produced by sanity checks like this:

```
typedef char ruby_check_sizeof_long[SIZEOF_LONG == sizeof(long) ? 1 : -1];
```

What could be the cause of this issue?  gcc and mysql are both 64 bit - are there any other binaries/libs that would cause this issue?

For the record, there is a copy of the mysql2 gem already installed on this system.  It was installed a couple years ago by the original developer, and is tied to a ruby install in /usr/bin.  I'm trying to migrate a project over to using a ruby managed by rbenv.  From a clean ruby install made through rbenv, bundle install will work flawlessly on our ubuntu box, but it trips up with the mysql2 gem on this system.